# Ajax done call how to pass a variable by copy

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $.when(
    $.ajax({url: "./dorequest.php?id=" + list[i],
        success: function(response){ jsonFriendlist = response; }}) ).done(
        function(jsonFriendlist) {
            var friendListObject = JSON.parse(jsonFriendlist);
            if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(friendListObject)) {
                var rawListFriend = friendListObject.friendslist.friends;
                for (var j = 0; j < rawListFriend.length; j++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    playerLinkList[i].listFriends.push(rawListFriend[j].id);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

}

Basicly I try to update a part of an object in the array `list` sending a request by item i that array. But the code fail because every call to the "done" function i done with i = 13 (which is `list.lenght`).
My understanding is that since the request take time to be send an retrieve the result and since it's done async when the done function is call the main thread is already out of the `for`so i = 13.

My question is how can I manage to "freeze" i by passing it by copy when the ajax request is sent ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a closure solved the issue.

```
for (var i = 0; i < playerIds.length; i++) {
    // Pass the parameter "i" to the done functions
    (function(index) {
        var dfd = $.ajax({url: "./dorequest.php?id=" + playerIds[i] + "&requesttype=friendlist",
                success: function(response){ jsonFriendlist = response; }});

        dfd.done(
                function(jsonFriendlist) {
                    var friendListObject = JSON.parse(jsonFriendlist);
                    if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(friendListObject)) {
                        var rawListFriend = friendListObject.friendslist.friends;
                        for (var j = 0; j < rawListFriend.length; j++) {
                            playerLinkList[index].listFriends.push(rawListFriend[j].steamid);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    })(i);
}
```